# How to call REST api result json having c# keywords

Tags: c#, json, rest, api, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to access a simple REST Api, https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/btc-usd

The result of the same is like this format:

```
{"ticker":{"base":"BTC","target":"USD","price":"9969.76308171","volume":"127575.47420967","change":"-197.36472278"},"timestamp":1517410741,"success":true,"error":""}
```

Now, when I am trying to get result from it, I find ticker objet of json null, timestamp and error objects are getting filled.

So, I suspect there might be the problem datamembers are not matching with json text. My Modeldto looks like this:

```
public class CurtoUsd
    {
        public ticker tick { get; set; }
        public Single timestamp { get; set; }
        public bool success { get; set; }
        public string error { get; set; }
    }

public class ticker
    {
        public string _base { get; set; }
        public string target { get; set; }
        public string price { get; set; }
        public string volume { get; set; }
        public string change { get; set; }
    }
```

Please have a look, I was suppose to use base as variable but it is the keyword, so instead i used _base.

And I am using httpclient to in asp.net core 2.0 webapi and the code looks like this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            if (client.BaseAddress == null)
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.cryptonator.com/");
            }
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(baseUrl);
            CurtoUsd usdrate = new CurtoUsd();
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                usdrate = await response.Content.ReadAsJsonAsync<CurtoUsd>();
            }
            return CommonFunctions.ConvertDouble(usdrate.tick.price);
```

Detail

```
 of function:
public static class HttpContentExtensions
    {
        public static async Task<T> ReadAsJsonAsync<T>(this HttpContent content)
        {
            string json = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            T value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
            return value;
        }
    }
```

May I know what's wrong I am doing? Is the point I have pointed out correct, is there any solution if it is so.

Please help.

Comment: If you are using Json.NET you can you the `[JsonProperty(name="someName")]` attribute.  This will allow you to call your class properties anything you want, while still serializing and deserializing into the properties of the json

Comment: are you using json.net? because `ReadAsJsonAsync` is not a `HttpContent` method

Comment: I am using Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: I was really unaware about this [JsonProperty(name="someName")]. in Newtonsoft, it reads as this: [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "base")]

Comment: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json); this step is the culprit. I can see json is having full data but while converting to Type value, it loses tick as ticker and shows null.

Comment: You can use `@` in C# to use keywords as identifiers, e.g. `foo.@base.@class`.

Comment: Ok, great @maccettura, your answer is perfect, I made change as per Newtonsoft and one more wrong definition was "tick", I changed it to "ticker" and it worked fine.

Comment: @Dai, I will definitely try.

Comment: Inside the ticker class, rename `_base` to `Base`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use @ in C# to use keywords as identifiers, e.g. `foo.@base.@class`.

So your DTO becomes:

```
public class Ticker
{
    public string @base  { get; set; } // Escape the `base` keyword with `@`
    public string target { get; set; }
    public string price  { get; set; }
    public string volume { get; set; }
    public string change { get; set; }
}
```

Note that you should use `PascalCase` for type identifiers n C#/.NET (so `class Ticker` instead of `class ticker`), and for public members too.

Note that Newtonsoft.Json is actually case-insensitive for member names by default (unless you specifically configure it otherwise) so you can use PascalCase for the properties, this also stops them from being C# keywords too, and it will still work:

```
public class Ticker
{
    public string Base   { get; set; } // `Base` is not a keyword
    public string Target { get; set; }
    public string Price  { get; set; }
    public string Volume { get; set; }
    public string Change { get; set; }
}
```